# Create one chart which can will plot values from another sheet into a chart named as "countChart". i want only one chart in my workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

i am trying to plot values from another sheet, but each time i run the macros  it creates  a chart everytime i run it. is there a way where i can create only one chart (like we do in sheets, create one sheet if its not already exits, and then add values to it) and the plot the values as the values changes in another sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub chartAdd_v2()

Dim chartSheet As ChartObject

Set chartSheet= Charts.Add

chartSheet.SetSourceData Worksheets("count_issue").Range("A2:c17")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub chartAdd_v2()

    With Charts
        If .Count = 0 Then
            .Add
        End If
        .Item(1).SetSourceData Sheets("count_issue").Range("A2:C17")
    End With

End Sub
```

Create if not existing

```vb
Sub mycharts()

    Const CHART_NAME = "issues"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim cht As Chart, bHasChart As Boolean
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Count_issue")
   
    For Each cht In wb.Charts
        If cht.Name = CHART_NAME Then bHasChart = True
        Exit For
    Next
  
    If bHasChart Then
       Set cht = wb.Charts.Item(CHART_NAME)
    Else
       Set cht = wb.Charts.Add
       cht.Name = CHART_NAME
    End If
    cht.SetSourceData ws.Range("A2:C17")
    
End Sub
```

Comment: heyy thankyou now if i want to check the chart title name, what do i have to do.

Comment: @AniruddhHS Do you mean you want to check the name of all existing charts on the sheet. ?

Comment: yes, i want to make a chart with title "issues" and if there is a way to add changes to the same chart everytime the macros is ran, like create the chart once and update values to it everytime the macro is ran,